# google timeline chart connect to php mysql

Tags: php, charts

Right now my timeline chart doesn't show up at all in my web page I am not sure what is wrong with my code is not given me any errors.

I think this could be something to do with the date format I set but I am not sure. I double checked the date format and the one I am using it is matching with my database.

I would be grateful if you could point out where when wrong. 
Thanks

```
<?php
$sth = "SELECT * FROM goal WHERE account_id =$account_id";
$result4 = mysqli_query($con,$sth) or die(mysqli_error());
$rows = array();
$flag = true;
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
  array('type' => 'string', 'label' => 'goalName'),
    array('type' => 'date', 'label' => 'starts'),
    array('type' => 'date', 'label' => 'finish'));

//$rows = array();
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4)) {
$temp = array();
$starts = date("Y-m-d"); 
$finish = date("Y-m-d"); 

$temp[] = array('v' => (string) $rows['goalName']); 
$temp[] = array('v' => (string) $rows['starts']); 
$temp[] = array('v' => (string) $rows['finish']); 
$rows[] = array('c' => $temp);}

$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
//echo $jsonTable;
?>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':    [{'name':'visualization',
   'version':'1','packages':['timeline']}]}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {

var container = document.getElementById('example3.1');
var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
var data = "" google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo json_encode($table,  JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>);

var options = {
    title: 'Progress',
    is3D: true
var options = {
timeline: { colorByRowLabel: true }
};

chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Friend the detail is in the var option being interpreted twice so you see:

```
var options = {

    title: 'Progress',
    is3D: true
var options = {

timeline: { colorByRowLabel: true }

};
```

and should be as follows when

```
var options = {

    title: 'Progress',
    is3D: true,
     timeline: { colorByRowLabel: true }
};
```

I hope it will help you